# Merge 2 tables into 1 in R, and find cov matrix

Tags: r

I have two tables t1 and t2 that I want to merge into t.

Also I want to compute the covariance matrix from this merged table t.

Do someone know how to do this?

t1:

```
 [1,]           NA
 [2,]           NA
 [3,]           NA
 [4,]           NA
 [5,]           NA
 [6,]           NA
 [7,]           NA
 [8,]           NA
 [9,]           NA
[10,]           NA
[11,]           NA
[12,]           NA
[13,]           NA
[14,]  0.142590683
[15,]  0.011568591
[16,]  0.018059883
[17,] -0.016358564
[18,]  0.022469206
[19,] -0.001496580
[20,]  0.011924817
[21,]  0.097827640
[22,]  0.057392250
[23,] -0.047477360
[24,]  0.009535887
[25,] -0.044440812
```

t2:

```
 [1,]            NA
 [2,]            NA
 [3,]            NA
 [4,]            NA
 [5,]            NA
 [6,]            NA
 [7,]            NA
 [8,]            NA
 [9,]            NA
[10,]            NA
[11,]            NA
[12,]            NA
[13,]            NA
[14,]  0.0168113203
[15,]  0.0159771525
[16,]  0.0005493382
[17,] -0.0194076262
[18,] -0.0088486945
[19,] -0.0539383989
[20,]  0.0184048698
[21,]  0.0444103717
[22,]  0.0144223499
[23,]  0.0142368869
[24,] -0.0256929079
[25,] -0.0604034245
```

I tried with:

> t <- merge(t1,t2)

I want them to merge horisontal, not vertical.

Comment: we need a reproducible example, and one question at a time, and to know what you've tried

Comment: I gave you a downvote because the question is too broad and with no reproducible example data. If you can improve your post, I will consider to retract my downvote and give you an upvote.

Comment: I have not seen any improvement yet, so I am voting to close this post as it is too broad to me. Again, if you can improve your post, I will retract my closing vote.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it is still not reproducible, please consider to use dput to share your data. I have retracted my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the following

```
M <- cbind(t1, t2)
tail(M)
#              V1          V2
# 20  0.011924817  0.01840487
# 21  0.097827640  0.04441037
# 22  0.057392250  0.01442235
# 23 -0.047477360  0.01423689
# 24  0.009535887 -0.02569291
# 25 -0.044440812 -0.06040342
```

Note that `t1` and `t2` are not called tables in R. These are matrices of a single column. And you want not to merge them (as you could see with your attempt, that's a valid and very useful function, but not for this case) but to combine into a single matrix of two columns.

Further, taking into account that there are some NAs:

```
var(M, na.rm = TRUE)
#              V1           V2
# V1 0.0030173136 0.0009903913
# V2 0.0009903913 0.0009795797
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you would like?

```
mat <- rbind(t1,t2)
covmat <- cov(mat)
```